# Spring boot data jpa APPLICATION FAILED TO START

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I learn JPA from https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/#initial and git clone project

I did a java file following this example but it is still error.
How can I fix it?

### -----------

### -----------

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-06-09 16:41:37.706 ERROR 18872 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).

### ---------

### ---------

```
pom.xml file
```

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>gs-accessing-data-jpa</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <name>Spring Releases</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>org.jboss.repository.releases</id>
        <name>JBoss Maven Release Repository</name>
        <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <name>Spring Releases</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Answer (score 0):

You used `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` in your `pom.xml`. But I guess, no data source adjusted in `appllication.properties` file. If you wanna use DB connections, `application.properties` file should contain configurations like this:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=mysqluser
spring.datasource.password=mysqlpass
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080/myDb?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
```

Otherwise if you don't use jpa, remove spring-boot-starter-data-jpa dependency from pom.xml:

*remove:*

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And then try again to run the application.